# auto enter input after click label dataTable in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to click label and after auto enter input search.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPmHY.jpg)

Here is a code example:

```
$('form#dataTable-form').on('click', '.label', function () {
    var keyword = $.trim($(this).text());
    $('input.input-sm').val(keyword).focus();
});
```

I want result.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLjGx.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: What's not working? That looks reasonable enough. Perhaps you need to include the markup, at least for the `.label` and `input.input-sm` elements.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Datatables search() API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()).

Answer (score 0):

Search the table using a custom input:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
   table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```